# Normalise values based on two bands

Tags: math, statistics

I have data that comes from different sources with different typical ranges, like so:

```
VALUE  LOWERBAND  UPPERBOUND
5      2          7
6      1          10
2      1          4
22     3          8
...
```

I would like to normalise VALUEs with respect to LOWERBAND and UPPERBOUND, but as I have no background in statistics I really can't see how it could be done. Any pointers?

To put it in other words, I guess I would like to rescale VALUES so they would all belong to the same LOWERBAND and UPPERBOUND (perhaps the global mean LOWERBANDs and UPPERBOUNDs?)

Comment: You need to decide to what distribution (e.g. Normal) the lower and upper bands belong, and which points of the distribution these points represent.  Then you need to skew the distributions in each row of your table.

Comment: They are fairly normally distributed.

Comment: OK then if you can figure out how to skew a normal distribution then you are in business.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are after is something like the following:

1. Move the lower bound to zero:

   newValue = oldValue - LOWERBOUND
2. Calculate the value as a percentage of the upper bound (scale 0 - 100)

   newValuePercent = (newValue / UPPERBOUND) * 100

In you example the last value is btw. outside the [LOWERBOUND, UPPERBOUND] range... so not sure whether you want to limit it at the end or not